# Backup and Restore Oracle database in Azure

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, azure

Has anyone recreated an on-premise Oracle Database in the cloud and specifically an Azure Database(Oracle) Instance?

The total size of the database I want to recreate as backup in the cloud is around 260GBs and the version is Oracle 10G.

The two options I can see it's either RMAN(via tape) or a database dump(exp or expdp). What is the most efficient and trouble-free way out of these two? My opinion is that a database dump could be a better option, however I am worried in terms of performance and running all those insert statements from scratch. Any thoughts?

Any help gladly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The question is about finding the best way to replicate the on-premise database to Azure. Correct - I am aware that Azure provides ready VMs with Oracle so planning to use these bearing in mind licensing: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-oracle-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Oracle databases in Azure are not provided as DBaaS, you get OS access, so it does not really affect the choice.

RMAN is efficient when working with large databases, while Data Pump is trouble-free and is easier to manage for someone not familiar with DBA tasks. A 260 GB database is not big, I would just export-import the database.

To restore an RMAN backup, you need the same platform + the same or higher software version. If your software version is higher, you need to immediately upgrade the database after restoring it.

With Data Pump you can just import the data directly to a higher version database, even on a different platform. Loading data with Data Pump is usually fast. The slow parts are creating indexes and validating constraints. This is a one-time operation, it should not affect performance in a negative way. In fact, it reorganizes tables and indexes, it may even improve the performance depending on their current state.